# The side menu closes after clicking on subitem

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, menu

I created a side menu. After expanding, for example, *First element*, when I click *First subitem*, the whole list with subitem closes. All the code seems to be correct, because the template in html, css and js is working. But when I insert link into *href*  and click in one of the subitem, the whole sublist closes again. To sum up - after switching to another page, the entire menu restarts. But I'd like list of submenus was still open. I have reviewed similar topics but have not been able to implement any solution. Sorry, but I'm newby in front-end. Below are the pieces of code. I will be grateful for your help.

```js
$('.feat-btn').click(function() {
  $('nav ul .feat-show').toggleClass("show");
  $('nav ul .first').toggleClass("rotate");
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? family= Poppins:wght@300 & display=swap') * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0: user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #1b1b1b;
}

nav ul {
  background: #1b1b1b;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none
}

nav ul li {
  line-height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

nav ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

nav ul li a {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
}

nav ul ul {
  position: static;
  display: none;
}

nav ul .feat-show.show {
  display: block;
}

nav ul ul li {
  line-height: 42px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #e6e6e6;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: cyan;
  background: #1e1e1e;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover {
  color: cyan!;
  background: #1e1e1e;
}

nav ul li a span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}

nav ul li a span.rotate {
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="feat-btn">First element<span class="fas fa-caret-downfirst"></span></a>
      <ul class="feat-show">
        <li><a href="some link">First subitem</a></li>
        <li><a href="some link">Second subitem</a></li>
        <li><a href="some link">Third subitem</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the url as follows:

**1. with `javascript:void(0)`**

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="loginlink">login</a>
```

**2. with Disable handle**

```html
<a href="Some link" onClick="return false;" id="loginlink">login</a>
```

**3. with you can replace tag `a` by tag `span`**

**4. with `href="#"`**

```html
<a href="#" id="loginlink">login</a>
```